# How do I get a div to appear outside it's container, and scroll, while keeping overflow on it's container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress blog design, and running into an issue with the entry-header. I would like my entry-header to be offset, going outside the bounds of it's container, yet scrolling with the content, inside the content wrap. Here is a screenshot of what i'm trying to achieve.
[image: screenshot of blog design]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1oO0.png)

I'd like to have the red areas scroll along with the text of the blog post, but so far, the only way I've been able to get the red areas to be offset as seen above, is to set position: absolute. When position is set to relative, it shows up as seen below.
[image: blog design with position relative]

Do you have any ideas that could help me resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Better provide us a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) code. Also looking at screenshots, it feels like you are not giving enough `width` for that(div with that red background).

Comment: Ok, I'm working on that now.

Comment: @divy3993 Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsk9fvts/

Comment: Do you have it online? could you provide the Link?

Comment: @divy3993 http://basil-gen.marathonwp.com/blog/

Comment: I want the issue online, So i could help you. I did not find the content on link provided.

Comment: My collegue changed the color scheme and some of the filler text, but that link is where the content is. I just tested the link provided and it did go to the page I expected. What content are you seeing there?

Comment: What i really see is this: http://i.imgur.com/0oTZ9QO.png

Comment: [Try this link](http://basil-gen.marathonwp.com/blog/)

Comment: Na, Nothing different over there too. all the same.

Comment: I rechecked the site, and noticed that it was having some caching issues. I fixed those issues, so the correct content should be loading. I went to look at your imgur photo, but it told me the image was removed. [Try this link now, see if it's different](http://goo.gl/KI3bim).

Comment: Ok ya got it, wait i will let you know when i am done with it.

Answer (score 0):

As user @divy3993 states a fiddle would be helpful.

**Anyway**: The overflow of your outer div seems to be hidden. This is the reason why you don't see the left part of your header when position is relative.

Apply the css-property

```
overflow-x: visible;
```

to your outer div (the one with the dark background) and the full header should be shown.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for keep you waiting.. I had a while no look at SO.
Sadly the solution that i was thinking of (with pure CSS) does not work as it is pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1402667 the combination of

```
overflow-x: visible
```

and

```
overflow-y: auto
```

won't work as expected.

So it seems you have to use JavaScript to solve your issue. I had a look at the link that you are pointing out in comments (http://basil-gen.marathonwp.com/blog/) and successfully run the following jQuery code there:

```
var $headers = $('.site-inner h1');
var $scrollContainer = $('.site-inner .content-sidebar-wrap');

var hideShowHeaders = function(visibleTop, visibleBottom){
    $headers.each(function(){
        if($(this).show().offset().top < visibleTop || $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() > visibleBottom){
            $(this).hide();
        }else{
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
};

$headers.each(function(){
    $(this).data('initTop', $(this).position().top);
});

hideShowHeaders($scrollContainer.offset().top,  $scrollContainer.offset().top + $scrollContainer.height()); //might consider borders

$scrollContainer.scroll(function(){
    $headers.each(function(){
        $(this).css('top', $(this).data('initTop') -  $scrollContainer.scrollTop() );
    });
    hideShowHeaders($scrollContainer.offset().top,  $scrollContainer.offset().top + $scrollContainer.height()); //might consider borders
});
```

It essentially repositions the headers whenever your content container is scrolled. When the headers (or a part of those) would not be visible with `position:relative` those headers are hidden. In all other cases they are shown.

As i mentioned it's jQuery-Code so you need to include jQuery yet and e.g. execute above code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ...code above
});
```

If you want to straight test it you can browse to your site (http://basil-gen.marathonwp.com/blog/) open Javascript-Console,
inject jQuery via javascript e.g. like

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

and then execute above code in Javascript-Console (when directly testing it you should not have scrolled before executing javascript code).

---

I should mention that the code above is not perfect since it only shows and hides headers instead of showing e.g. 50% of it. I couldn't come up quickly with a solution for it. Anyway you could do this with a more complex showHideHeaders-function where marked lines need to be implemented

```
var hideShowHeaders = function(visibleTop, visibleBottom){
    $headers.each(function(){
        if($(this).show().offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() < visibleTop){
            if($(this).offset().top  < visibleTop){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                //lower part of this header needs to be displayed
                var bottomPxToShow = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() - visibleTop;
                var hiddenPx = $(this).outerHeight() - bottomPxToShow;
                //show lower bottomPxToShow Pxs of header
            }
        }else if($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() > visibleBottom){
            if($(this).offset().top > visibleBottom){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                //upper part of this header needs to be displayed
            }
        }else{
            //show full header
        }
    });
};
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: I'm working on the fiddle, but I haven't really used it before, so I'm working on figuring out the best way to put it in there. Also, on that outer div, I do have overflow set to auto. The goal is to have the list of blog posts contained within that div, but to have the entry-header appear outside of it.

Comment: ok... what happens if you set overflow-x: visible and overflow-y: auto?

Answer (score 0):

give it position relative with higher z-index

```
position:relative;
z-index:10;
left:-50px;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugvkdq66/)

Comment: your fiddle also works without the z-index property. So this cant be the cause of the problems

Comment: Yeah that is right it would not work if the `#container` has `overflow:hidden` even with higher z-index thanks